# elasticsearch - nested document sort/score with typical e-commerce data

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to move our ecommerce search system to elastic search. We have a bunch of products and each product can have multiple offers (sold by merchants). Roughly the format of the document is

```
{
    "productId": 1234,
    "title": "Apple Macbook Pro",
    "description": "Macbook Pro ModelNo:ABC 2.4GHz 8GB RAM",
    "offers": [
        {
            "offer_id": "123",
            "offer_seller": "ebay"
            "offer_price": 900
            "condition": "refurb"
            "times_bought": 25,
        },        
        {
            "offer_id": "124",
            "offer_seller": "amazon"            
            "offer_price": 1200,
            "condition": "new",
            "times_bought": 35,
        },
        {
            "offer_id": "125",
            "offer_seller": "bestbuy"                        
            "offer_price": 1400
            "condition": "new",
            "times_bought": 10,
        }
    ]
}

{
    "productId": 1235,
    "title": "Apple Macbook Air",
    "description": "Macbook Air ModelNo:ABC 1.2GHz 4GB RAM",
    "offers": [

        {
            "offer_id": "123",
            "offer_seller": "ebay"
            "offer_price": 600
            "condition": "refurb"
            "times_bought": 50,
        },        
        {
            "offer_id": "124",
            "offer_seller": "amazon"            
            "offer_price": 999,
            "condition": "new",
            "times_bought": 55,
        },
        {
            "offer_id": "125",
            "offer_seller": "bestbuy"                        
            "offer_price": 1100
            "condition": "new",
            "times_bought": 20,
        }
    ]
}
```

**Some more facts**:

1. The offers are updated at a higher rate than products.
2. There are 50 offers on an average for every product.

Here is the query I have

```
{
"query" : {
"function_score": {
    "boost_mode": "replace",
    "multi_match": {
         "query": "macbook",
         "fields": [
            "title^10",
            "description^5"
         ]
      },
    "script_score": {
        "params": {
            "param1": 2,
            "param2": 3.1
        },
        "script": "_score * doc['offers.times_bought'].value / pow(param1, param2)"
    }
}
}
}
```

**My Questions**
1. I went with nested type for offers as I would like to use the offer_price to sort the products. I [read](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/2917) that parent/child doesnt support sorting, but the fact every update to a offer will reindex the whole product makes me wonder whether parent/child is a better choice.
2. I would like to show the best(1 or 2) offers for each products that are returned. Is there a way to sort the nested documents for each returned result or should i do that by myself ?
3. If I want to store the 'times_bought' outside the index as it gets updated more frequently than anything else in the index. how do i plug it into ranking ? Can I extend elastic search scoring classes and modify it use this external data structure ?

Any suggestions/recommendation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

- Doing the 'best offer' aggregation in your indexing code. Which would mean you store it in a KV-store (redis, couchbase, whatever) and repopulate every time an offer for a particular product changes. You probably have the data available anyhow to do this.
- That way you just index `_price` to refer to the price of the best offer.
- THis correctly returns the products in the right order.
- Lastly (after ES has returned the products in order) you do a call on product-id(s) to your kv-store to fetch the entire top (1 or 2) offers for each of the returned products.

This combination of ES and a KV-store may seem more trouble than it's worth, but trust me it works wonders to keep complexity down in the end.

That answers 1 and 2.

As for 3: 
You could probably model that as a parent/child, which would allow for indexing with separate intervals, performance trade-off but I'm not really sure to be honest.

hth a bit

Comment: The ranking I described above (sort by times_bought) is the simplest one. I would like to use a more sophisticated version which will boost some offers (based on seller or price of the offer) depending on the user or keyword. Therefore, I would be unable to pick one offer during index time. Another use case is I would like to let users filter by seller_name or by price, so if i remove offers during index time, I would loose all the data.

Comment: it's one of the more difficult usecases for ES as it currently stands (which is why I suggested the rough workaround :).  It would be trivial to implement what you want and more if you could afford to use SOLR instead which provides a feature called FieldCollapsing (i.e.: 'grouping'). See: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing. This is a long awaited feature in ES: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/256